# Win32 WM_PAINT and a child window

Tags: winapi, paint, onpaint

How to draw inside a child window?

I thought I should create the main window `CreateWindow(WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPCHILDREN)` with some `WndProc` (without `WM_PAINT`). On its `WM_CREATE` I create another window `CreateWindow(WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPCHILDREN)` with another `WndProc2` which reacts to `WM_PAINT`.
However, it seems that the another handler enters an infinite loop. What am I doind wrong?

Please, don't you have an advice or examle?

PS: WS_CLIPCHILDREN doesn't seem to effect this, and both `WndProc` default to `DefWindowProc`

The code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Proc2(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            printf("-------\n");
            return 0;
        case WM_PAINT:
            printf("-");
            return 0;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
...
case WM_CREATE:
    CreateWindowClass(hInstance, Proc2, "Window2");
    w2 = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_STATICEDGE, "Window2", "Win", WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, 0, 0, 100, 100, hWnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);


void createWindowClass(HINSTANCE hInstance, WNDPROC WndProc, LPCSTR lpszClassName)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = "test";
    wc.lpszClassName = lpszClassName;
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);
}

int WINAPI WinMain
...
createWindowClass(hInstance, WndProc, "MainWindow");
w = CreateWindow("MainWindow", "Main", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

Comment: Do you return 0 after doing the WM_PAINT handling? Beyond that ... show us your wndprocs and your Create and your RegisterClass calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be calling BeginPaint and EndPaint in response to the WM_PAINT message to validate the window.  Otherwise, the system thinks that your window has not been painted and so it will send the paint message again (and again).  See the [Microsoft documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922583.aspx)